# Как узнать реальный адрес функции(на основе данных из IDA + CheatEngine)

Tags: ассемблер, reverse-engineering, ida-pro

Имеется библиотека с разного рода [функциями](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jiUc.png), мне в этой библиотеки необходимо изменить 1 из функций .

Для поиска нужной функции я использовал IDA, которая мне выдала конкретный статичный адрес нужной мне функции - `0x1008F870` [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgJeX.png);

Но при запуске программы, по этому адресу - ничего нету.По какой причине это происходит ?
В более ранних версиях этой же самой библиотеки, таких проблем нету, тот адрес что выдает ида можно использовать для инжекта. И если это своего рода динамичное построение, то каким образом IDA выдала именно такой адрес? Либо если это своего рода защита, как ее можно обойти ?И как мне тогда определить реальный адрес функции, который идет в память.

Я так же пытался ставить хук на [Href](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpzM2.png)  `.text:1008F870 sub_1008F870    proc near               ; DATA XREF: .rdata:101B4C3Co` Но это никакого результата не дало

Comment: IDA показывает вам виртуальный адрес, который соответствует ImageBase из заголовка файла. DLL может на раз грузиться по адресу, отличному от ImageBase и, соответственно, будет другой адрес. Пробуйте отнять от 0x1008F870 базовый адрес из заголовка и прибавить к этому реальный адрес загрузки DLL.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов а как примерно выглядит базовый адрес и где он храниться ?, + на счет реального адреса вы имейте ввиду узнать его через тот же CheatEngine ? Нету ли какого то полного примера где пошагово видно что и как берется ?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Задам вопрос по другому - через что можно просмотреть базовый адрес ?

Comment: IMAGE_DOS_HEADERS + IMAGE_NT_HEADERS. Ну и общее представление о структуре MZPE нужно иметь.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов - такс ImageBase Я определил, а как вот определить LdrLoadImage( реальный адрес загрузки)

Comment: GetModuleHandle(dllName) вернет адрес в контексте процесса, от которого была вызвана функция, но раз вы смотрите для чужого процесса - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx может пригодиться.

Comment: Т.е если к примеру мой код выполняется через библиотеку Ogg.dll то через GetModuleHandle(NWidnow.dll) Я не получу тот самый адрес загрузки ?

Comment: Получите, если ваша DLL загружена в нужный процесс. Это несложно проверить.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов хм вот такое обращение `HMODULE UStructserl;
 UStructserl = GetModuleHandleA("NWindow.dll");
 wsprintfA(buffer, "%d", UStructserl);
 MessageBoxA(0, buffer, "TextBuff test", MB_OK); `  выдает мне 0 при загрузке, я что то не так сделал ?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Такс ну вроде бы чуток разобрался, через тот же CheatEngine я так понял это http://i.imgur.com/W6qcH1x.png - Адрес Загрузки 0x05E80000, но опять же он динамичен, мне осталось понять только как это автоматизировать - и вы можете публиковать ответ в целом! спасибо, надеюсь разберусь...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Через GetModuleHandle не срабатывает, поскольку мне нужно получить адрес уже загруженного модуля(NWindow.dll) а не грузить его снова , т.к. ноль вовзращает - как  это можно решить ?

Comment: Чтением документации это можно решить. В особенности на указанную функцию и на GetLastError.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов - выдает Ошибку 126(Не найден) - может проблема в том как я делаю Инжект ?  http://pastebin.com/u9w1nm0K , мой код находиться внутри ogg.dll возможно она загружается раньше Nwindow.dll, или дело в другом ?

Comment: Посмотреть в отладчике список модулей вам религия запрещает смотреть?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Я просто пока - не на том уровне чтобы точно знать, как следует действовать - вот список http://i.imgur.com/ppBy4G3.png Просто я не пойму как это поможет решить эту ошибку 126 ? Или вы имейте ввиду что нужно через - обращение кодом, просмотреть этот список и сделать Snapshot?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Да уж - либа Nwindow.dll просто грузиться позже - ogg.dll из которой я пытаюсь сделать запрос, чтож тогда делать ?Как заставить в коде ждать пока загрузиться Nwindow И только потом делать GetModuleHandle ?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов у меня там кстати подключен BeaEngine Отладчик, это как то может помочь при выполнении ? Мне же нужно что то типа этого http://www.cyberforum.ru/post4905214.html ожидать загрузки .dll, и потом уже применять код, очень хочу эту тему добить...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ну что Опубликуйте ответ ?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Ну что вы опубликуйте ответ чтобы не оставлять так ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDA показывает вам виртуальный адрес, который соответствует ImageBase из заголовка файла. DLL может на раз грузиться по адресу, отличному от ImageBase и, соответственно, будет другой адрес. Пробуйте отнять от 0x1008F870 базовый адрес из заголовка и прибавить к этому реальный адрес загрузки DLL.

Comment: А еще такой момент, могу ли я используя стандартные Hook методы типа detoor trampoline, вместо функции - подставлять класс, внутри которого будет искомая функция. Ибо на данный момент у меня все выглядит следующим образом http://pastebin.com/nTVT6PYB , и класс подставить в HookFunctionWithTrampoline(org, class) - не получается, да и обозначить класс.функцию как Int fastcall не получается.